# How to pass different instances while multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am building a scraper. My goal is to start X browsers (where X is number of threads) and proceed to scrape a list of URLs with each of them by splitting that list in X parts.

I decide to use 3 threads (3 browsers) with list of 10 URLs.

**Question: How to separate each task between the browsers like this:**

1. Browser1 scrapes items in the list from 0 to 3
2. Browser2 scrapes items in the list from 4 to 7
3. Browser3 scrapes items in the list from 8 to 10

All browsers should be working at the same time scraping the passed list of URLs.

I already have this `BlockingCollection`:

```
BlockingCollection<Action> _taskQ = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

public Multithreading(int workerCount)
{
        // Create and start a separate Task for each consumer:
        for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Consume);
}

public void Dispose() { _taskQ.CompleteAdding(); }

public void EnqueueTask(Action action) { _taskQ.Add(action); }

void Consume()
{
// This sequence that we’re enumerating will block when no elements
// are available and will end when CompleteAdding is called. 
foreach (Action action in _taskQ.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            action();     // Perform task.
}
public int ItemsCount()
{
        return _taskQ.Count;
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
Multithreading multithread = new Multithreading(3); //3 threads
foreach(string url in urlList){

    multithread.EnqueueTask(new Action(() => 
    {
         startScraping(browser1); //or browser2 or browser3
    }));
}
```

I need to create the browsers instances **before** scraping, because I do not want to start a new browser with every thread.

Comment: "...because I do not want to start a new browser with every thread" - then how will any work be done in parallel?

Comment: @MitchWheat, I mean that I want to start X browsers from the beginning of the program and use them until the end. What I usually do is a loop that starts a browser, does its job, closes the browser. Isn't there a way to start all browsers in the very beginning and use them until the end?

Comment: Why should Thread 1 process URLs 0..3 ? What would be wrong with it doing 0, 3, 7, ... ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, sorry, I should have made that clearer. The actual order does not matter, that was just an example. I just want the links split equally between all browsers (threads).

Comment: Why equally? If one site turns out to take lots more time, should the other threads go idle?

Comment: Are you going to queue more work as it runs or is it a known amount of work at the start or the program?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I just thought it would be easier to split the urls equally between all threads since they take the same time to process. I do not really care about the number of URLs per thread as long as all threads are constantly working (until the list is completed)

Comment: @weston, the amount of work is known at the start of the program.

Comment: Do you know about [`AsParallel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: When it comes to keeping a number of threads busy, the parallel extensions are better than anything you can come up with yourself.

Comment: Not sure what your end goal is here, if it is just to grab the HTML response from a URL, the HttpClient class would be a good shout. It supports await able tasks too so if your running .net 4.5 I'd have thought that would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Taking Henk Holtermans comment into account that you may want maximum speed, i.e. keep browsers busy as much as possible, use this:

```
private static void StartScraping(int id, IEnumerable<Uri> urls)
{
    // Construct browser here
    foreach (Uri url in urls)
    {
        // Use browser to process url here
        Console.WriteLine("Browser {0} is processing url {1}", id, url);
    }
}
```

in main:

```
    int nrWorkers = 3;
    int nrUrls = 10;
    BlockingCollection<Uri> taskQ = new BlockingCollection<Uri>();
    foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, nrWorkers))
    {
        Task.Run(() => StartScraping(i, taskQ.GetConsumingEnumerable()));
    }
    foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, nrUrls))
    {
        taskQ.Add(new Uri(String.Format("http://Url{0}", i)));
    }
    taskQ.CompleteAdding();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the usual approach is to have a single blocking queue, a provider thread and an arbitrary pool of workers.

The provider thread is responsible for adding URLs to the queue. It blocks when there are none to add.

A worker thread instantiates a browser, and then retrieves a single URL from the queue, scrapes it and then loops back for more. It blocks when the queue is empty.

You can start as many workers as you like, and they just sort it out between them.

The mainline starts all the threads and retires to the sidelines. It looks after the UI, if there is one.

Multithreading can be really hard to debug. You might want to look at using Tasks for at least part of the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could give some `Id` to the tasks and also Workers. Then you'll have `BlockingCollection[]` instead of just `BlockingCollection`. Every consumer will consume from its own `BlockingCollection` from the array. Our job is to find the right consumer and post the job.

```
BlockingCollection<Action>[] _taskQ;
private int taskCounter = -1;
public Multithreading(int workerCount)
{
    _taskQ = new BlockingCollection<Action>[workerCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
    {
        int workerId = i;//To avoid closure issue
        _taskQ[workerId] = new BlockingCollection<Action>();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> Consume(workerId));
    }
}

public void EnqueueTask(Action action)
{
    int value = Interlocked.Increment(ref taskCounter);
    int index = value / 4;//Your own logic to find the index here    
    _taskQ[index].Add(action);
}

void Consume(int workerId)
{
    foreach (Action action in _taskQ[workerId].GetConsumingEnumerable())
       action();// Perform task.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using background workers can limit the number of threads:

```
public class Scraper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Action> tasks;
    private readonly IList<BackgroundWorker> workers;

    public Scraper(IList<Uri> urls, int numberOfThreads)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++)
        {
            var url = urls[i];
            tasks.Add(() => Scrape(url));
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
        {
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Action task;
                while (tasks.TryTake(out task))
                {
                    task();
                }
            };
            workers.Add(worker);
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    public void Scrape(Uri url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scraping url {0}", url);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```